# Using SQL Stored Procedure vs Databricks in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a requirement to write upto 500k records daily to Azure SQL DB using an ADF pipeline.
I had simple calculations as part of the data transformation that can performed in a SQL Stored procedure activity. I've also observed Databricks Notebooks being used commonly, esp. due to benefits of scalability going forward. But there is an overhead activity of placing files in another location after transformation, managing authentication etc. and I want to avoid any over-engineering unless absolutely required.
I've tested SQL Stored Proc and it's working quite well for ~50k records (not yet tested with higher volumes).

But I'd still like to know the general recommendation between the 2 options, esp. from experienced Azure or data engineers.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is enough information to make a solid recommendation. What is the source of the data? Why is ADF part of the solution? Is this 500K rows once per day or a constant stream? Are you loading to a Staging table then using stored procedure to move and transform the data to another table?

Here are a couple thoughts:

1. If the data operation is SQL to SQL [meaning the same SQL instance for both source and sink], then use Stored Procedures. This allows you to stay close to the metal and will perform the best. An exception would be if the computational load is really complicated, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.
2. Generally speaking, the only reason to call Data Bricks from ADF is if you already have that expertise and the resources already exist to support it.

Since ADF is part of the story, there is a middle ground between your two scenarios - Data Flows. Data Flows are a low-code abstraction over Data Bricks. They are ideal for in-flight data transforms and perform very well at high loads. You do not author or deploy notebooks, nor do you have to manage the Data Bricks configuration. And they are first class citizens in ADF pipelines.

Comment: I'm loading once per day from an ADLS Gen1 source file. It doesn't support Data Flows for the format type. Only loading to a single staging table in SQL DB and no further data movement.

Comment: Between the source and dest there is simple summation of columns to derive new columns

Comment: One option would be to run a Copy from Gen1 to an intermediary type (Blob or Gen2) prior to the Data Flow, which could easily be deleted as part of the Data Flow. Or you could just keep doing what you are doing using SPROCs. The real take away is that Data Bricks is almost certainly not necessary or worthwhile in your case.

Answer (score 1):

As an experienced (former) DBA, Data Engineer and data architect, I cannot see what Databricks adds in this situation.  This piece of the architecture you might need to scale is the target for the `INSERTs`, ie Azure SQL Database which is ridiculously easy to scale either manually via the portal or via the REST API, if even required.  Consider techniques such as loading into heaps and partition switching if you need to tune the insert.

The overhead of adding an additional component to your architecture and then taking your data through would have to be worth it, plus the additional cost of spinning up Spark clusters at the same time your db is running.

Databricks is a superb tool and has a number of great use cases, eg advanced data transforms (ie things you cannot do with SQL), machine learning, streaming and others.    Have a look at this free resource for a few ideas:

https://databricks.com/p/ebook/the-big-book-of-data-science-use-cases

Comment: Yes it would be worth avoiding additional resources. Unless SQL procedures have some limitations in prod. environment

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question was asked three years ago, I would like to share my personal experience as my project is currently in a transformation from stored procedures to Databricks.

The use case here is to process ~1.5M entries per run and do some minimal transformation before uploading it to SQL Server.

The decision drivers were:

- Maintainability in fluctuating world: The stored procedures code existed for years and did their job. Problem was that it was written and maintained by one dedicated SQL database admin/engineer who left the project and therefore the internas of the stored procedures. It was really hard for new developers (who are not SQL experts) to understand what is going on as the code was messy and distributed across several stored procedures.
- Standardization: There are actually multiple ETL pipelines which were implemented partially in stored procedures, partially in another customized way. The hope with Databricks is to be able to orchestrate all the pipelines in a single source of truth.
- Version control: With having the stored procedures on the database basically anybody could do changes without being noticed or option to go back to previous state.
- Testability: There were also no unit tests or any other tests that would have helped to understand the business logic implemented in there or that validates the business logic.

I think with some effort we could have achieved all this also without Databricks, but the tooling there really helps a lot in establishing a maintainable and higher quality ETL pipeline.

Also it will enable the project for future business cases by having the new infrastructure ready.

Actually, in this project, we felt the overhead migrating to Databricks was worth it to have a more transparent, high-quality and maintainable solution.